# Как вывести средний рейтинг пользователя из БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

У меня есть SQL запрос для подсчета среднего рейтинга пользователя на сайте. Есть таблица users с информацией о пользователях и отдельная таблица ratings с оценками. Стараюсь подсчитать среднее арифметическое по каждому пользователю.

```php
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`!='.$_SESSION ['user']['id'].'');
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $sqlr = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT AVG(rating) AS RatAvg FROM ratings WHERE `user_id` = '.($result ['id']).'');
    while ($resultr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlr)){
        $final = round($resultr['RatAvg'], 1);
    }
}
```

На странице вывожу всех пользователей из БД и их средний рейтинг. Сейчас почему-то у всех отображается рейтинг одного и того же пользователя. По конкретному user_id рейтинг считается правильно, но вот с динамическим выводом проблема.

```php
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`!='.$_SESSION ['user']['id'].'');
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo
        '  <div class="users_container">
                <h>'. ($result ['user_name']) .' '. ($result ['user_surname']) .'</h>
                <p class="user_list_info">'. ($result ['user_mail']) .'</p>
                <p class="user_list_info">'. ($result ['user_phone']) .'</p>
                <p class="user_list_info">г. '. ($result ['user_city']) .'</p>
                <p class="user_list_rate">'.$final.' &#9733</p>
        </div>';
    }
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту проблему и всем пользователям вывести свой рейтинг. Я новичок и не уверен, что вообще в правильном направлении двигаюсь для решения этой задачи.

Comment: откройте для себя удивительный мир `inner join` и `group by` и не насилуйте базу запросами в цикле

Comment: Вы все правильно делаете, но это можно сделать одним запросом. Почитайте про джоины и группировку. Пару дней сэкономит вам кучу нервов в будущем. Единственное, для подключения к базе лучше использовать PDO.

Comment: Спасибо! Кажется я смог добиться того же результата с помощью JOIN.
`$sqlr = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT AVG (ratings.rating) as AvgRat, users.id
 FROM ratings
 JOIN users ON users.id = ratings.user_id');
while ($resultr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlr)){
    $final = round($resultr['AvgRat'], 2);
}`
Но по-прежнему у всех отображается рейтинг одного и того же пользователя. Не пойму как создать цикл для вывода у каждого пользователя своего рейтинга. Не могли бы Вы мне подсказать?

Answer (score 0):

Ничего удивительного, переменная $final постоянно перезаписывается при прохождении цикла, так как это не массив:

```
$final = round($resultr['RatAvg'], 1);
```

Проще всего выводить информацию сразу по получению от БД:

```
$sqlr = mysqli_query($connect, 'SELECT AVG (ratings.rating) as AvgRat, users.id  FROM ratings  JOIN users ON users.id = ratings.user_id'); 
while ($resultr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlr)){
    echo
        '  <div class="users_container">
                <h>'. ($resultr ['user_name']) .' '. ($result ['user_surname']) .'</h>
                <p class="user_list_info">'. ($resultr ['user_mail']) .'</p>
                <p class="user_list_info">'. ($resultr ['user_phone']) .'</p>
                <p class="user_list_info">г. '. ($resultr ['user_city']) .'</p>
                <p class="user_list_rate">'.round($resultr['AvgRat'], 2).' &#9733</p>
        </div>';  
}
```